# Why I can't create new grails application in Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: grails, netbeans, groovy

**OS**: Windows 10 
**JDK**: jdk1.8.0_65 
**IDE**: Netbeans 8.2

**Steps I had taken:** 
1. I had installed Netbeans, selecting the ALL column, meaning it can support Groovy or the grails application. 
2. I also had installed the latest version of Grails which is the **grails-3.3.5**. 
3. After installing everything, I opened Netbeans.

**STEPS I HAD TAKEN IN NETBEANS**
File > New Project > Groovy > Grails Application > then I clicked next. 
After that I had clicked the **Configure Grails...** button. Then I copy pasted the file path of my grails home directory (in my case that is **C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\grails-3.3.5**) under the textbox of *Grails Home* then clicked on OK.

The problem here is that I cannot create a new project. It kept on displaying this message box: "**Unexpected error occured while creating the application. See output window for more details.**" 
And there it shows the error: "**Specifiy an application name or use --inplace to create an application in the current directory**"

What should I do? Please help me. I need this for my job application's exam. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get exactly the same error as you when creating a Grails 3.3.5 project in NetBeans 8.2 on Windows 10. This is because of a longstanding bug in NetBeans: [Bug 258407 - Error when creating a Grails 3.1.x project](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258407), which also impacts more recent releases of Grails.

Although that bug has **Status: VERIFIED FIXED**, unfortunately the fix was not applied to release 8.2 itself (*"...this bug is fixed in development builds not 8.2"*). You have two possible workarounds:

- Install a DEV build of NetBeans 8.x which contains the fix.
- Install the beta release of NetBeans 9.0 which contains the fix.

**Option 1**: Using a DEV release of NetBeans

- Download [the most recent nightly Dev build of NetBeans 8.2](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/).
- Activate Groovy and locate Grails 3.3.5 in the same way as you did on NetBeans 8.2.
- You can then successfully create your Grails application using the **Groovy > Grails Application** project wizard, and run it:

[image: DevBuildGrails1]

**Option 2**: Using a beta release of NetBeans 9.

- Download and unzip NetBeans 9 beta from the [Apache NetBeans 9.0 Beta](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html) web site.
- Start NetBeans 9 beta and install the Groovy/Grails plugin:

[image: InstallGrailsPlugin]

- Locate Grails 3.3.5 in the same way as you did on NetBeans 8.2 (**Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Groovy > Grails Home**).
- You can then successfully create your Grails application using the **Groovy > Grails Application** project wizard, and run it:

[image: Beta9Grails]