# how to enable gradle for Netbeans?

Tags: gradle, groovy, netbeans, plugins, netbeans-11

I enabled groovy through `options > miscellaneous` but don't see a plugin for gradle.  How do I enable gradle for Netbeans 11?

see also:

[does netbeans 11 support grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55543696/262852)

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-users/201910.mbox/browser   so Netbeans doesn't support the gradle kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have already installed and activated **Groovy**, **Gradle** is enabled in NetBeans 11 simply by installing the **Gradle** plugin.

All NetBeans plugins are installed through the **Tools > Plugins** screen. To install the **Gradle** plugin:

- On the **Plugins** screen click the **Available Plugins** tab.
- Click the **Name** column header to sort the entries by name.
- Locate the entry named **Gradle**, check it, then click the **Install** button:

  [image: gradlePlugin]
- The **Gradle** plugin will be downloaded and installed. No restart will be required if that is the only plugin being installed.

To verify that the installation of the **Gradle** plugin was successful:

- On the **Plugins** screen click the **Installed** tab.
- Check the **Show Details** checkbox.
- Scroll down and verify that there is an entry for **Gradle**:

  [image: installedPlugins]

Comment: hmm, I wasn't see the gradle plugin.  Thanks, I'll look again.

Comment: @Thufir [1] I just reinstalled the Gradle plugin again, and it worked fine, so I'm not sure why you can't see it. [2] Perhaps try clicking the **Check for Newest** button on the **Available Plugins** tab first if you can't see an entry for Gradle? [3] Another thing to try is clearing the cache. See [How to clear the cache in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8689780/2985643). It may not help, but trying won't do any harm. [4] Another approach would be to install the **Groovy and Gradle** plugin instead, if you can see that. It's in my first screen shot just below the **Gradle** entry.

Comment: @Thufir Also take a look at [Groovy and Grail plugin is missing in Netbeans IDE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54490958/2985643). I realize you are on NB 11, not NB9, but it still might be helpful.

Comment: It seems to be installed now, I saw a message when NB launched and it ran some updates.  I'm futzing with it now:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56577513/262852

Comment: Man I dont know if you know this but you are a hero, thanks!