# how to correct red "import" error messages from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, classpath, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I created a project using `gradle init --type java-application --test-framework testng --dsl kotlin` but Eclipse shows:

[image: eclipse]

For what it's worth, this runs fine:

```
thufir@dur:~/eclipse-workspace/baseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/eclipse-workspace/baseX$ gradle clean run

> Task :run
Oct. 06, 2019 6:35:33 P.M. org.basex.examples.local.LoadXML <init>
INFO: {databaseName=books, dataResource=books.xml}
Oct. 06, 2019 6:35:34 P.M. org.basex.examples.local.LoadXML createDrop
INFO: Name   Resources  Size  Input Path  
----------------------------------
books  0          4570              

1 database(s).


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/eclipse-workspace/baseX$
```

How can I remove the red error messages from Eclipse?  Usually I've kept to Netbeans, but am [switching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56577513/262852) over.

Comment: You need to [add the gradle dependencies to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908208/2970947). The message is **not** erroneous.

Comment: Does it work without `--dsl kotlin`?

Comment: I'll have to try it without the `--dsl kotlin` @howlger