# No output build from gradle with third-party library

Tags: java, gradle

I'm having trouble using gradle to build some project files from over at https://github.com/Hopding/JRPiCam.  I am forcing myself to start learning gradle this week, but so far my cursory internet searches have given me only a vague sense of what gradle even does.  I'm assuming that it's used to help keep track of disparate files hosted at varying locations across the internet, and maybe with file versioning.  Anyways, for right now I would just like to compile a class into a Jar file and begin using it in my code to automate the camera on my raspberry Pi.  The directions say to clone the directory onto my local computer, change the directory to the download location, and then, from the Windows PowerShell, use the command: **./gradlew jar** to output a build directory where the compiled jars will reside.  I followed the instructions,  and though I received no error message, I also received no output directories.  Nothing at all.  I have installed gradle 6.9 on Windows 10 and made sure the path variable is set appropriately.  So here is my question: 1. If I have this directory structure:[image] , can I just cd into there and use a gradle command to compile?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: [1] You are asking two distinct questions here (Getting Gradle to work without NetBeans, and getting Gradle to work using NetBeans), but on SO a post should only ask one question. You can post as many questions as you want, but only one question per post. [2] Regarding _"What do I need to do to get gradle to work within Netbeans?"_, see [how to enable gradle for Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56529528/2985643).

Comment: Thank you for the help...I altered the question to reflect the guidelines.