# Java EE Server not found when importing project in NetBeans with JDK 17 and Tomcat 10

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am facing an issue when importing an external project into NetBeans. The error message "Missing Java EE Server" is displayed, even though I do not encounter this problem when creating a new project from scratch.

When I click "Resolve Problem", the list of servers is not displayed. Additionally, when I try to add a new server, the error message "Tomcat with the same Catalina Home folder is already registered" appears.

I have attached the screenshot of the error message for your reference.

Please advise on how to resolve this issue.

**Additional information:**

- Operating system: Windows 10
- NetBeans version: 13
- JDK version: 17
- Tomcat version: 10.0.10

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Installing the Java EE plugin: I have installed the "Java EE Development Kit" and "Java EE Web" plugins in NetBeans.

Configuring the Tomcat server: I have configured a Tomcat server in NetBeans with the correct "Catalina Home" directory and Java version.

Deleting and recreating the project: I have deleted and recreated the project, but the issue persists.

Comment: You are trying to use Tomcat 10.0, which expects to use Jakarta Servlet 5.0. See the [Tomcat versions overview](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). Jakarta Servlet 5.0 is part of the Jakarta EE Web Profile [version 9](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/9/jakarta-webprofile-spec-9#web-profile-definition). Your error message refers to "Jakarta EE 10", which [uses Jakarta Servlet 6.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/10/jakarta-webprofile-spec-10.0#web-profile-definition). So, referring back to the Tomcat versions overview, that suggests...

Comment: ...you may need to use Tomcat v10.1, and not Tomcat v10.0.

Comment: Tomcat is not a JavaEE server. Create a TomEE server, or a glassfish, or any other tha actually is a javaee server. Please note that the JavaEE spec of your project must align with the javaee version of the server.

Comment: @PauloAraújo - minor point, but here, we are referring to JakartaEE, not JavaEE; also you can use a [suitable subset](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) of JakartaEE and run quite happily on Tomcat. (Or an older version of Tomcat if you want to use JavaEE).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple problems.

- You need more than JSTL to make web app
- You mysteriously have a double set of JSTL libraries. Perhaps you pulled in two different versions?
- You have the wrong version of Tomcat.
- [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), like the similar [Eclipse Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)), does *not* implement the [Web Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE#Web_profile) (see [spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/)) of [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE). Tomcat supports a subset of the Jakarta technologies that make up Web Profile. So your install of Tomcat may not be qualified to be listed in your dialog box selecting "Available Jakarta EE 10 Web compatible servers".

Regarding Tomcat versions, see [*Which version?*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page on the Apache Tomcat web site.

- Tomcat 11.0 for Servlet 6.1 & JSP 4.0 (Jakarta EE 11) (Java SE 17 or higher)
- Tomcat 10.1 for Servlet 6.0 & JSP 3.1 (Jakarta EE 10) (Java SE 11 or higher)
- Tomcat 10.0 for Servlet 5.0 & JSP 3.0 (Jakarta EE 9) (End-of-life, migrate to 10.1)
- Tomcat 9 for Servlet 4.0 & JSP 2.3 (Jakarta EE 8)

---

You really should be using a build system to assist with making a web app. Most popular are [*Apache Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) (XML based) and [*Apache Gradle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) ([Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Groovy) based). NetBeans supports Maven, and apparently Gradle too via a plugin per [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56529528/642706).